# WPF Window not being destroyed if Content s from another source

Tags: wpf, garbage-collection, window

Firstly, I am very proficient at WPF and rarely get thrown by things, and rarely ever have to post a question. To be fair, I have only ever used one main Window with all embedded Content so it is really flat so this is the first time I have had to use additional floating Windows.

I have a Window that I raise after assigning it a View Model to its Content properly which duly shows and renders as expected using the data template etc. I hook into the Window.Close event after creation and remove the Close even method when closed. Pseudocode as follows:

Creating the Window:

```
private void CreateWin()
{
  // Just in case a previous instance is open
  CloseWin();

  _myWin = new Window()
  {
    Content = new MyViewModel()
  };

  _myWin.Closed += OnMyWinClosed;
  _myWin.Show();
}
```

When the Window is closed:

```
private void OnMyWinClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CloseWin();
}
```

Cleanind up:

```
private void CloseWin()
{
  if (_myWin == null)
    return;

  _myWin.Content = null;
  _myWin.Closed -= OnMyWinClosed;
  _myWin = null;
}
```

I run the code to create the Window and set the content to the view model and when the I close the Window it soon gets destroyed and all is OK.
Now the issue:

The view model that I am assigning is not necessarily complex but it does a few things, even then, it is probably not relevant but, if I assign an existing view model that is still in memory rather than a new instance of the same view model type (as this code shows), I can create 50 instances of the Window but they do not get destroyed until the application terminates.

My actual window is a subclassed Window so that I can add a breakpoint to the ~ destructor to check the finalisation. I have also called the following just to make sure but no destruction, although a bit over the top:

```
GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect()
```

You will also notice, for extra measure, that I set the Window.Content = null afterward just to really detach it from the Window.

Nothing in the associated view, model, or data template has any events hooking the view model to the UI other than the inbuilt PropertyChanged. However, that should also make no difference, and also the same view model independently set has no issue.

My application went from about 110MB to 420MB when opening all so I could also see the memory creep up. I have a good laptop so is it that it would eventually clear but takes longer for larger objects? If that is the case then that does not make sense.

In summary, it almost seems that ViewModel’s assigned to a Window.Content property will prevent the Window from being garbage collected if the ViewModel is from another source and not created on the fly for the specific Window.

Surely that cannot be right?

Other points:
I have tried setting the Owner and not setting the Owner which makes no difference.
I have created these windows in a loop of 100 and destroying them to see if has anything to do with bigger objects taking a long time, but no change.

Comment: When the Window instance would be never get garbage collected after a simple Close(), then this would indicate a bug. Window is the root element of a rendered WPF application. So this cheap and easy to detect bug in such an important control would disqualify WPF from being a serious and reliable high quality framework. This bug is too cheap, so others would have identified it long before.

Comment: So we can agree upon that it is not Window or a buggy GC that is the source of the issue. So obviously it must be your client code that produces the leak. In order to help you, you must post a small example code, that is able to reproduce the exact issue.

Comment: I had a similar issue with creating a lot of windows and that they would stay in memory. How do you instantiate those windows? Show or ShowDialog? Look into dispatcher and invoke shutdown method.

Comment: Thank's for the responses. I totally agree with the first point that WPF should be solid enough. There must be a bug and I am still trying to track it down but the Window is instantiated as the code snippet shows, with just Show(). As stated the only difference is that Window.Content = new ViewModel() allows it tobe destroyed and Window.Content = ExisginViewModel holds it in memory. This is the the same ViewModel type.

Comment: Sorry I should have read the question more carefully. I see how you instantiate the window. I used the same to generate some pdf documents and had the same issue. When you destroy the window can you check if the viewmodel event handler for property changed is removed? or maybe store all of the event handlers and see if any of those are holding a ref to that window. Sometimes GC pushes window to gen1 collection.

Comment: Thank you for that and there is nothing holding o to the Window at all, equally, setting the Content and DataContext to null should clear all. I have decided, for now, to change what I do and create one Window and keep it in memory thereafter. I have intercepted the Closing event, set Cancel = true, and called another event to hide the Window. When I next need it I just re-use it. The cost is one (presumably empty) Window in memory which is nothing. This is used to display a floating search result and the user may do this several times a day and only one Window needs to be present.